# How does one stream step's output using `gh watch`?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Using `gh` I'm able to watch my run to completion, which shows something like the following:

```
✓ My cool job · 1663894809
Triggered via push about 18 hours ago

JOBS
✓ Build, push and run cloud artifacts in 1m57s (ID 4739289825)
  ✓ Set up job
  ✓ Checkout
  ✓ my_custom_step
  ✓ Post Checkout
  ✓ Complete job
```

Is it as of now possible to also watch the output of all the steps ***while*** the job is running? Practically exactly what running `gh run view --log --job ....` shows, but instead of seeing the logs after the fact, having the logs being streamed during the job's lifetime without accessing the github UI. It would thus show the following:

```
✓ My cool job · 1663894809
Triggered via push about 18 hours ago

JOBS
✓ Build, push and run cloud artifacts in 1m57s (ID 4739289825)
  ✓ Set up job
... Long list of logs...

  ✓ Checkout
... Long list of logs...

  ✓ my_custom_step
... Long list of logs...

  ✓ Post Checkout
... Long list of logs...

  ✓ Complete job
```

Comment: there's an open issue about this: https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/3484

Comment: @rethab Thanks so much. I guess that answers the question. If you could and if it's within the standards of StackOverflow, could you answer this questions with the fact that it's not possible and that it's listed on the roadmap so that I can mark it as solved? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of January '22, this is not possible, but there is an open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/3484